Changing exception type in NestJS
In my architecture I have a repository get function that makes a database request in a try-catch block and returns not found exception if no user exists. In a login function, I invoke the repository get function, but would like to throw unauthorised exception instead of not found. How would I do this? From what I understand nested try-catch blocks do not call each other.
My current code is something like
async get_user(email){
  try {
    db.user.findOrThrow(email);
  } catch (e) { 
    throw new NotFoundException;
  }
}

async login (email) {
  try {
    get_user(email);
  } catch (e) {
    throw new UnauthorisedException;
  }
}

But a call to login with non-existent email returns 404 instead of 401.

You need to add AWAIT for the function call

authorization is at the http level so instead of throwing new NotFoundExeption,
throw new HttpException('Forbidden', HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)


The issue was not in try-catch blocks, but in my server hooks handling the authentication before it reached the controller. I am closing the question now.
